# PostgreSQL - Rule to create a copy of the primaryID table

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-database

In my schema I want to have a primaryID and a SearchID. For every SearchID it is the primaryID plus some text at the start. I need this to look like this:

- PrimaryID = 1
- SearchID = Search1

Since the PrimaryID is set to autoincrement, I was hoping I could use a postgresql rule to do the following (pseudo code)

```
IF PRIMARYID CHANGES
{
SEARCHID = SEARCH(PRIMARYID)
}
```

This would hopefully occure exactly after the primaryID is updated and happen automatically. So, is this the best way of achieving this and can anyone provide an example of how it is done?

Thank you

Comment: Why do you want to store that value at all if can be derived from the primaryID. Just create a view that returns the "calculated" searchID. Much cleaner in my opinion. But if you think you have to store it, use a trigger instead of a rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Postgres 11** introduced genuine generated columns. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

For older (or any) versions, you could emulate a "virtual generated column" with a special function. Say your table is named `tbl` and the serial primary key is named `tbl_id`:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION search_id(t tbl)
  RETURNS text STABLE LANGUAGE SQL AS
$$
SELECT 'Search' || $1.tbl_id;
$$;
```

Then you can:

```
SELECT t.tbl_id, t.search_id FROM tbl t;
```

Table-qualification in **t**.search_id  is *needed* in this case. Since `search_id` is not found as column of table `tbl`, Postgres looks for a function that takes `tbl` as argument next.

Effectively, `t.search_id` is just a syntax variant of `search_id(t)`, but makes usage rather intuitive.