# PostgreSQL - ERROR: column does not exist SQL state: 42703

Tags: sql, postgresql, column-alias

I am trying to do a cohort analysis and compare average number of rentals based on the renter's first rental year(= the year where a renter rented first time). Basically, I am asking the question: are we retaining renters whose first year renting was 2013 than renters whose first year was 2015?

Here is my code:

```
SELECT renter_id, 
       Min(Date_part('year', created_at)) AS first_rental_year, 
       ( Count(trip_finish) )             AS number_of_trips 
FROM   bookings 
WHERE  state IN ( 'approved', 'aboard', 'ashore', 'concluded', 'disputed' ) 
  AND  first_rental_year = 2013 
GROUP  BY 1 
ORDER  BY 1;
```

The error message I get is:

```
ERROR:  column "first_rental_year" does not exist
LINE 6: ... 'aboard', 'ashore', 'concluded', 'disputed') AND first_rent...
                                                             ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "first_rental_year" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 208
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: i dont see the error part on your query you posted... the correct syntax should be `AND extract(year from b1.created_at)`

Comment: Are you sure this is the same query? Error message is saying LINE 10?

Comment: Sorry guys, added the correct error message

Comment: The problem is that the column `first_rental_year` is not in your source table. Other SQL engines support syntax such as `AND CALCULATED first_rental_year = 2013`, but postgre doesn't. You could reuse your formula (`AND Min(Date_part('year', created_at)) = 2013`) or better, use @Juan Carlos' solution which avoids this redundancy. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql) for more info.

Comment: I can't reuse my formula because it says that aggregate functions aren't allowed in the WHERE clause

Comment: i'd belong in the having clause but i'd go with @Juan Carlos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
SELECT renter_id,
       Count(trip_finish) AS number_of_trips 
FROM (
        SELECT renter_id, 
               trip_finish,
               Min(Date_part('year', created_at)) AS first_rental_year
        FROM   bookings 
        WHERE  state IN ( 'approved', 'aboard', 'ashore', 'concluded', 'disputed' ) 
     ) T
WHERE first_rental_year = 2013  
GROUP  BY renter_id
ORDER  BY renter_id ;
```

Comment: This looks correct all it needs is T.first_rental_year, T.renter?? Right Juan or am i full of shi?

Comment: The problem is you cant use the alias `first_rental_year` on the where, because at that time the alias doesnt exist. So you create the alias inside a subquery and use it outside.  You also can change the alias and use the function `Min(Date_part('year', created_at))  = 2013`

Comment: ERROR:  column "t.first_rental_year" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT *
               ^

********** Error **********

ERROR: column "t.first_rental_year" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
SQL state: 42803
Character: 8

Answer (score 4):

**ERROR:**

> SQL Error [42703]: ERROR: column XYZ does not exist

Check you have **double quotes** around Column Fields:

**BAD:**

```
update public."AppTime" t Set "CustomTask"= 'XYZ' where  t.SharedAppId = 12890;
```

**GOOD:**

With double quotes around "SharedAppId"

```
update public."AppTime" t Set "CustomTask"= 'XYZ' where  t."SharedAppId" = 12890;
```

> If you created the table without quotes, you should not use quotes when querying it, and vice versa. [This is explained in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS): "If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it"

Comment: not really relevant for this question

Comment: @eis completely relevant, it produces the same error message and this is the SO thread for answers. Disappointing you've been here longer than me and don't appreciate people sharing knowledge :(

Comment: 1) even if it would produce the same error, in this thread the problem was different, and 2) The answer is ill-advised. If you want to go through the route of using quotes, you really should explain it all - when to quote and when to not quote. If you created the table without quotes, you should *not* use quotes when querying it, and vice versa. This is [explained in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS): "If you want to write portable applications you are advised to always quote a particular name or never quote it".