# Possible to calculate a column in DB table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, calculated-columns

PSQL noob here. I'm trying to create a table similar to the following:

```
name foo    bar    baz     foo_per_bar      foo_bar_per_baz
joe  28     11     18      = foo/bar      = foo_per_bar/baz
```

and thus far my schema looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE foobars (
id: serial primary key,
foo: Integer,
bar: Integer,
baz: Integer,
foo_per_bar: ??,
foo_bars_per_baz: ??
);
```

Is such a thing supported? 
If not, how could I go about doing it? Create a separate table that performs the calculations and reference it in `foobars`?

Comment: You can use a view for that

Comment: do you mind expounding on that a bit more? I'm really new to postgres

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql) post. It's the same idea.

Comment: This is against the [3NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form#.22Nothing_but_the_key.22) rule: "[Every] non-key [attribute] must provide a fact about the key, the whole key, and nothing but the key."