# Calculated fields in database - Laravel

Tags: laravel

What is the best practice to store calculated fields in database.

For example, lets say a table has fields height, weight, bmi

A user enters height weight values and bmi field is automatically filled. How to achieve this with a form.

Formula for bmi
$bmi = weight / (height * height)

Tried the following
Profile Model

```
protected $table = 'profiles';

protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'weight', 'height', 'dob', 'age', 'bmi'];

public function user(){
  return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

protected static function boot() {
  parent::boot();

  static::saving(function($model){
      $model->bmi = $model->weight / ($model->height * $model->height);
      $model->age = (date('Y') - date('Y',strtotime($model->dob)));
  });
}
```

Profile Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
  {
      $profile = new Profile();
      $profile->weight = $request->get('weight');
      $profile->height = $request->get('height');
      $profile->dob = $request->get('dob');
      $profile->age;
      $profile->bmi;
      $profile->save();
      return back()->with('success', 'Your profile has been updated.');
  }
```

But im receiving an error

```
Illuminate \ Database \ QueryException (42S22)
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'weight' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `users` (`weight`, `height`, `dob`, `bmi`, `age`, `created_by`, `updated_by`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (60, 175, 1988-04-03, 0.0019591836734694, 30, 2, 2, 2018-03-08 20:06:02, 2018-03-08 20:06:02))
```

Comment: before inserting the values to the table, you need to calculate the bmi manually and assign it to the `$yourObject->bmi = $calculatedBmi`

Comment: So can i use the same forumla $calculateBmi = $request->weight / ($request->height * $request->height)

Comment: Yes you can use the same $request object values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this in the `boot` method of the model:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($model){
        $model->bmi = $model->weight / ($model->height * $model->height);
    }); 
}
```

Comment: why should we need this in `boot` ?

Comment: You could stop yourself from having to handle the calculation in mulitple places in a controller and instead just do it once in a boot method.

Comment: @KPK That's one of the ways of setting an observer on an Eloquent model.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I've edited to be `static::saving` instead of `static::creating`, as you'd expect the BMI to update when the height/weight do.

Comment: do i need to mention the model name in place of model i mean  static::saving(function($profile){

Comment: @SrikanthGopi You can use `static` or you can use the name of the mode. up to you.

Answer (score 7):

> What is the best practice to store calculated fields in database.

In general, **don't**. It's redundant - your database already has all the information needed to compute it, so why store redundant data?

Instead, put [an accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators) on the model:

```
public function getBmiAttribute() {
    return ($this->weight / ($this->height * $this->height));
}
```

You can then do `$this->bmi` to get the computed value.

If you *must* have it in the database, use [an Eloquent event](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events). You'd probably want to hook into the `saving` event.

Comment: Im currently doing the same via model to display the bmi value in the view. But what im looking for is to save bmi value in database so that i can compare bmi values for users with dates. For example, showing user, your bmi levels were 21.0 last month and 20.0 today. A form is shown to the user on every week.

Comment: @SrikanthGopi keep in mind, you're still saving 1 bmi value in the database for each user. This will not help you in comparing month on month values. You would need to have a separate log table for doing this regardless of whether you save the values using an Eloquent model event

Comment: @Paras The code that i mentioned in the main question saves multiple profiles for a user. So i can fetch the profile on a weekly basis and compare it with previous profile. I'm doing this for the first time.

Comment: Oh so the profiles table is like a snapshot copy of the users table at a given point in time. Well you should think about the following: 1) Do you want to copy all the fields (e.g. dob, name that dont change in time)? 2) Do you want users to trigger the saving of profiles or perhaps use task scheduling instead? 3) In your `store` method, you aren't linking the user ID to the profile, maybe you missed it

Comment: @Paras Could you provide any reference link or exact search keywords where i could look at few tutorials and learn more about these. I'm new to coding. You make sense. I should not copy dob as it never changes. So users table(with values that dont change) and healthlogs table (with other values those change) should be the right approach??

Comment: @SrikanthGopi try searching when to use `normalized` v/s `denormalized` data. Also, try searching good database structures for `logging`. Caching may be premature for your use case but if you're up for learning beyond, go for it

Comment: Thanks @Paras ill learn the subjects you gave me and then try something better.

Answer (score 5):

As of Laravel 5.3 & MySQL 5.7, you can use [Column Modifiers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#column-modifiers) `virtualAs` and `storedAs` to create a `VIRTUAL` *(evaluated when rows are read)* or `STORED` *(evaluated and stored when rows are inserted or updated)* generated column for MySQL.

I've made use of `virtualAs` in the example below...

```
    Schema::create('results', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        ...
        $table->time('predicted_time')->nullable()->default(NULL);
        $table->time('handicap')->nullable()->default(NULL);
        $table->time('finish_time')->nullable()->default(NULL);
        $table->time('actual_time')->virtualAs('TIMEDIFF(finish_time, handicap)');
        $table->time('offset')->virtualAs('TIMEDIFF(actual_time, predicted_time)');
        ...        
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

> What is the best practice to store calculated fields in database.

It depends on your use case. If you're using a **relational database**, and your use case does not involve big data (in terms of volume, variety or velocity), the best practice is to not store calculated fields and calculate them on the fly.

If you're using a **noSQL** database (such as MongoDB, which is supported by Laravel) or **Hadoop**, the best practice is to store calculated fields to avoid computational time.

**In A Nutshell**

> It's a tradeoff between time complexity and space/storage complexity.
>   For big data / noSQL systems, store calculated fields especially if
>   they are computationally complex. For a relational database, calculate
>   them on the fly and keep your data non-redundant

**Laravel Solution for RDBMS:**

Use [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) like so:

```
public function getBmiAttribute($value)
{
    return ($this->weight / ($this->height * $this->height));
}
```

**Laravel Solution for NoSql**

Use [model events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/events#defining-events) like so:

```
protected static function boot() {
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function($model){
        $model->bmi = $model->weight / ($model->height * $model->height);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your DBMS supports computed columns (aka generated columns), you might consider utilizing them.

Highlights:

- Computed columns don't persist the data to the database (or if they do technically they'll be managed by the DBMS), so you're not duplicating any data or making anything redundant
- The calculation is then available outside of the application's code base for anything to use. For example, if there is a need to develop reporting with raw SQL queries then the calculation will be available there.
- Eloquent (Laravel's default ORM) will pick up the column without you necessarily needing to define it anywhere.

You could execute code to create it during a migration. For example, I had a use case where I wanted to simplify determining if something was currently published and I did it like this:

```
Schema::table('article', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->dateTime('published_at')->nullable();
    $table->dateTime('unpublished_at')->nullable();
});

$sql = "ALTER TABLE article ADD is_published AS CAST(CASE WHEN GETUTCDATE() BETWEEN ISNULL(published_at, '2050-01-01') AND ISNULL(unpublished_at, '2050-01-01') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BIT);";
DB::connection()->getPdo()->exec($sql);
```

Then after retrieving a record from the database I can determine if it's published by simply checking...

```
if ($article->is_published) ...
```

And if I want to query it from the database I can easily do...

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE is_published = 1
```

Note, this syntax is for T-SQL since the RDBMS for my project is MS SQL Server. However, other popular DBMS have similar features.

- MS SQL Server: [Computed Columns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table)

  ALTER TABLE dbo.Products ADD RetailValue AS (QtyAvailable * UnitPrice * 1.35);
- MySQL: [Generated Columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html)

  ALTER TABLE t1 ADD COLUMN c2 INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (c1 + 1) STORED;
- Oracle: [Virtual Columns](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_3001.htm#BABIDDJJ)

  ALTER TABLE emp2 ADD (income AS (salary + (salary*commission_pct)));

PostgreSQL doesn't seem to support it (yet), but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/3411515) SO answer provides a decent workaround.

Answer (score 0):

another way to make this
making a computed column in the migration
this working with all DB:-

```
 $table->computed ('tax','price * 0.27');
```

but this working with MySQL DB:-

```
 $table->integer('tax')->virtualAs('price * 0.27')->nullable();
 $table->integer('discount')->storedAs('price - 100')->nullable();
```