# A usually simple SQL join

Tags: postgresql, join, count

I need advice on doing a JOIN with PostgreSQl. I want to take the sum (or number of times id 1 is entered) of a single id and place it into  a new column in table b.

Table a

```
id  username   comment
1    Bob        Hi
2    Sally      Hello
1    Bob        Bye
```

Table b

```
id    something   total_comments
1       null            2
```

Comment: Why?  kind what analytical functions can be used for. Do you have a performance reason to store this value? as A changes (new or deleted records) does B's count need to be updated?  (even more of a reason to count at run time if it does)

Comment: These two tables will be for separate views.

Comment: Select into ? `SELECT * INTO B FROM (Select ID, count(*) from A group by ID) A`  But is this one time load.  Are you needing each time something changes in A to update B?? And lastly, what's this have to do with a a "JOIN"?  Similar question to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql  but i'm not sure what you're after

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger for insert, update, delete on the Table a to select the sum and update in Table b

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SELECT INTO` if table_b doesn't already exist.

```
SELECT
    id
  , NULL AS something
  , COUNT(comment) AS total_comments
  INTO table_B
FROM table_a
GROUP BY id
```

Or `INSERT INTO` if table_b does exist.

```
INSERT INTO table_b (id, something, total_comments)
SELECT
    id
  , NULL AS something
  , COUNT(comment) AS total_comments
FROM table_a
GROUP BY id
```