# postgresql - How to implement/use a view as a calculated column into a table

Tags: postgresql

my previous question was marked as already answered. However the suggested solution ([enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-columns-in-postgresql)) helped me only a little bit.
I want to know, how I get a view into my table structure or how to use the view as a column. With help of the suggestted solution I have created the following statement:

```
CREATE VIEW my_col4 AS
SELECT transaction.quantity * transaction.unit_price AS total_price 
FROM transaction
```

Next step was to execute the sql-statment: `SELECT * FROM my_col4`
My result is `130.00 €`

and this is the correct result of `quantitiy(10) * unit_price(13.00)`

But I don't know, how to implement this into my table, respectably how a further sql-statement should look like to get the following result:

```
|id  description  |  quantity  | unit_price  | total_price |
|1   Energy drink |  10        |     13.00   |    130.00   |
```

I hope my thoughts are correct and I'm looking forward to your answer.

Here is the sql-statement of my (shortened) table

```
CREATE TABLE public.transaction3
(
    id integer NOT NULL,
    description character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    quantity real NOT NULL,
    unit_price money NOT NULL,
    total_price money NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT transaction3_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
ALTER TABLE public.transaction3
    OWNER to postgres;
```

Comment: Sabine could you provide us the criteria or condition to join `transtraction3` table record with a `my_col4` view record ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The items after `SELECT` are actually (scalar) expressions. These could be plain column names, or expressions referring to column names. They can also contain functions referring to the column names , or functions *not* referring to any column. (such as  `random()` or`now()` )

---

```
CREATE VIEW my_transaction AS
SELECT t.id , t.discription
        , t.quantity , t.unit_price
        , t.quantity * t.unit_price AS total_price
          -- nonsense below this line ...
        , upper(t.discription) AS "CAPITALS"
        , now() AS heute
        , (random()* 1000000)::integer AS lottery_number
FROM transaction t
    ;
```

Comment: Thank you wildplasser,
your answer helped me to solve my problem.