# SQL : Error when adding column generated from other columns (postgresql 11)

Tags: sql, postgresql, generated

I try to add a column to my table which references the BMI and I already have 2 columns with height and weight. I want to generate automatically this column when I fill the 2 others. But I get an error and I don't find any answer to solve it.

```
CREATE TABLE player
(
    id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    height INT,
    weight INT
);

ALTER TABLE player ADD COLUMN bmi FLOAT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (weight/((height/100)^2)) STORED;
```

I get following error :

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near "(" 
LINE : ...E player ADD COLUMN bmi FLOAT GENERATED ALWAYS AS (weight/((h...

SQL state: 42601 Character: 61
```

Comment: Postgres does not (yet) support computed columns . . . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql.

Comment: Why do you want to store the BMI instead of calculating it in a Select/View? If you need an index you can use an Expression Index

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is for [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) rather than PostgreSQL:

```
col_name data_type [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expr)
  [VIRTUAL | STORED] [NOT NULL | NULL]
  [UNIQUE [KEY]] [[PRIMARY] KEY]
  [COMMENT 'string']
```

In general, each DBMS speaks its own SQL dialect, with often big differences. Save for very basic DML statements, you must stick to the documentation of the product you're using.

Answer (score 0):

Postgres has no support for computed columns but you can use triggers to simulate the behavior of computed columns.

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_player_computed
AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE f_tr_player_computed();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_tr_player_computed() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $player$
   BEGIN
      new.bmi = (new.weight/((new.height/100)^2));
      RETURN NEW;
   END;
```

**UPDATE:** Generated columns are being supported starting from Posgres 12

```
CREATE TABLE people (
   ...,
   height_cm numeric,
   height_in numeric GENERATED ALWAYS AS (height_cm / 2.54) STORED
);
```

Comment: This answer needs to be revised since the command is available since PostgreSQL 12: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this error also because I was thinking to run PostgreSQL 14 but then I run the command:

```
select version();
 -> PostgreSQL 11.7, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
```

The command `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` is available since PostgreSQL 12 (as far as I can see from the documentation here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html).

You can check an implementation (where you can try also your code) here:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0caf484b5b1a5e3453bdbc63fd64a3c2