# PostgreSQL 11.5 cascade update multi column of one row

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I hava one table named device_statistics,it store device info of one app,the table create scrip is:

```
CREATE TABLE public.device_statistics
(
    id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    abnormalcount integer,
    appid character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    inactivecount integer,
    offlinecount integer,
    onlinecount integer,
    statisticstime date,
    totalcount integer,
    CONSTRAINT ods_device_statistics_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

when a device offline,I must update the offlinecount value,since `totalcount=abnormalcount + inactivecount + offlinecount + onlinecount` so can I auto update totalcount value when abnormalcount,inactivecount,offlinecount or onlinecount updated.

for example:

before a device offline,the row like(only show we need):

```
appid  offlinecount totalcount

test        10            32
```

when a device offline and I update the offlinecount value,I want the follow row like:

```
appid  offlinecount totalcount
test       9           31
```

the value of totalcout is auto update,how to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before PostgreSQL 12, you could instead create a view:

```
CREATE TABLE public.device_statistics
(
    id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    abnormalcount integer,
    appid character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    inactivecount integer,
    offlinecount integer,
    onlinecount integer,
    statisticstime date,
    CONSTRAINT ods_device_statistics_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW public.device_statistics_with_total AS
SELECT id,
       abnormalcount,
       appid,
       inactivecount,
       offlinecount,
       onlinecount,
       statisticstime,
       abnormalcount + inactivecount + offlinecount + onlinecount AS totalcount
FROM device_statistics;
```

If you can afford to upgrade to PostgreSQL v. 12, you can use the new [generated columns feature](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-generated-columns.html):

```
CREATE TABLE public.device_statistics
(
    id character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    abnormalcount integer,
    appid character varying(32) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    inactivecount integer,
    offlinecount integer,
    onlinecount integer,
    statisticstime date,
    totalcount integer GENERATED ALWAYS AS (abnormalcount + inactivecount + offlinecount + onlinecount) STORED,
    CONSTRAINT ods_device_statistics_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Disclosure: I work for [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](http://enterprisedb.com)

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql

Comment: I understand what you say and it works well,thank you,