# Reverse a column in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-migration, ddl

So I have a table in SQL server that is defined as such

```
create table test(value varchar(200), Reverse(value) as valueReverse);
```

now when I insert something in this table lets say I insert the string hello, it will store the value in the table as such.

```
value | valueReverse
--------------------
hello | olleh
```

I am trying to convert the table into PostgreSQL however the reverse() function is not working and it's giving me errors. What is the correct way to create this table in postgres?

Comment: Could you show the error message?

Comment: Why are you doing that to begin with? is it to support a wildcard search at the beginning? In that case you can simply create an index on the expression, rather than adding a new column. Or use a trigram index.

Comment: The original table was designed by someone else, I'm currently looking at keeping the table structure the same, just to keep everything working smoothly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For PostgreSQL 12 and above**

If you are using Postgres 12 or higher then you can use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS` for the column `valueReverse` like below: [Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/ddl-generated-columns.html)

```
create table test(value varchar(200),
valueReverse varchar(200) generated always as (reverse(value)) STORED );
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=222003225e37a37ae0977e56423ea802)

**For PostgreSQL 11 or below**

For earlier version you can use `Triggers` like below.

**Creating Trigger Function**

```
create or replace function trig_reverse() returns trigger as
$$
begin
new.valueReverse=reverse(new.value);
return new;
end;
$$
language plpgsql
```

**Creating Trigger**

```
create trigger trig_rev 
before insert or update on test 
for each row 
execute procedure trig_reverse();
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=18e094d4ffe4f16d6af682b48ff43c3c)

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* store string twice (redundantly). It will be much cleaner and cheaper overall to store it once and produce the reverted copy on the fly. You can use a [`VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html) if you need a drop-in replacement for your table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE base_test(value varchar(200));
INSERT INTO base_test VALUES ('hello');
 
CREATE VIEW test AS
SELECT *, reverse(value) AS value_reverse
FROM   base_test;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=cac14c85807061a70df16a0bdc6a139c)*

Related:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)