# PostgreSQL - how to create a derived attribute which sums two attributes?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm struggling with creating a `totalCost` column that is the sum of `costA` and `costB` for each row.

```
CREATE TABLE Cost (
  customerId      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  costA           FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
  costB           FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
  totalCost       FLOAT(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (costA + costB) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (customerId)
);
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing? I would have thought this would be super simple!

Note - trying to build it in the DDL rather than a query.

Thank you! :)

Comment: sorry for the typo trailing comma! Now deleted. Still getting a syntax error at or near "("  thank you everyone for your help

Comment: Which version of postgres are you using? This works with postgres > 10.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8250729/5172513

Answer (score 0):

You have a trailing comma at the end. SQL doesn't allow that.

```
CREATE TABLE Cost (
  customerId      INTEGER NOT NULL,
  costA           FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
  costB           FLOAT(4) NOT NULL,
  totalCost       FLOAT(4) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (costA + costB) STORED,
  PRIMARY KEY (customerId),
                          ^ remove this
);
```

Note: since [`float(4)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-FLOAT) is imprecise, consider using the precise [`numeric`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL) type to store money.

Comment: `You have a trailing comma at the end` ... maybe avoid answering such typo questions if possible.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Says we can close them. Doesn't say anything about not answering them. It's a well formed question with a clear problem and example. Seems impolite not to answer, especially for a new user. Close it if you like.

Comment: [Don't use money](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money)