# Syntax for parameterized PostgreSQL function using dynamic SQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

This code:

```
ALTER TABLE myschema.mytable add column geom geometry (point,4326);
CREATE INDEX mytable_idx on myschema.mytable using GIST(geom);
UPDATE myschema.mytable set geom = st_setsrid(st_point(mytable.long, mytable.lat), 4326);
```

This works fine when updating a single table. How would you convert it into a dynamic SQL function,  with schema and table as parameters?

Comment: You're looking for dynamic SQL - `ALTER TABLE sch.tab` tries to alter the `"tab"` table in the schema `"sch"`, not resolving them to the parameters of the function. And your function expects two strings, so you'd need to call `SELECT create_geom('myschema', 'mytable');`

Comment: Ah. Want to write that up so I can accept your answer? :)

Comment: I don't know how to properly write dynamic SQL. I'd probably try making the function accept a [`regclass`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-oid.html) though, not two strings.

Comment: Thanks for the help; got it to work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the function input must be an existing table, the simplest *safe* way would be to use a `regclass` input parameter like demonstrated here:

- [Table name as a PostgreSQL function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705616/table-name-as-a-postgresql-function-parameter/10711349#10711349)

However, you also need the bare table name for the concatenated index name, so I'll stick with taking `text` for schema and table separately:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION create_geom(_sch text, _tab text)
  RETURNS void
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE format(   
'ALTER TABLE %1$I.%2$I ADD COLUMN geom geometry(POINT,4326);
UPDATE %1$I.%2$I SET geom = st_setsrid(st_point(long, lat), 4326);
CREATE INDEX %3$I ON %1$I.%2$I USING gist(geom);'
   , _sch, _tab
   , _tab || '_geom_gist_idx');
END
$func$;
```

Call:

```
SELECT create_geom('myschema', 'mytable');
```

Use a single `EXECUTE`, no need for multiple calls.

Just omit table-qualification for columns in the `UPDATE`. While not joining additional tables, column names are unambiguous. Else, use a table alias, which can be constant. Like:

```
UPDATE %1$s AS x SET geom = st_setsrid(st_point(x.long, x.lat), 4326);
```

But it's smarter to populate the column *before* you build the index. That's a lot faster and produces a balanced index without bloat. So I switched the commands.

Note how I concatenate the index name first (`_tab || '_geom_gist_idx'`), and *then* double-quote as required with `%3$I`. That's the safe way. Something like `%I_idx` fails with non-standard names.

**That said**, it's typically a mistake to add columns with redundant information to a table. (What keeps you from changing one or the other? Why bloat the table?) Either just use an expression index instead of all of the above:

```
CREATE INDEX ON myschema.mytable USING gist (st_setsrid(st_point(long, lat), 4326));
```

Or drop the now redundant `long` & `lat` from the table. Those can be extracted from the new `geom` cheaply on the fly.

Or, if you need all columns (for special performance reasons?), consider a **generated column** instead. See:

- [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql/8250729#8250729)

Answer (score 1):

Having your queries as SQL templates and using `format` function for identifiers:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.create_geom(sch text, tab text)
RETURNS void language plpgsql AS $body$
DECLARE
 DYNSQLA constant text := 'ALTER TABLE %I.%I add column geom geometry (point,4326)';
 DYNSQLB constant text := 'CREATE INDEX %I_idx on %I.%I using GIST(geom);';
 DYNSQLC constant text := 'UPDATE %I.%I set geom = st_setsrid(st_point(%I.long, %I.lat), 4326)';
BEGIN
    execute format(DYNSQLA, sch, tab);
    execute format(DYNSQLB, tab, sch, tab);
    execute format(DYNSQLC, sch, tab, tab, tab);
END;
$body$;

SELECT create_geom('myschema','mytable');
```

Comment: `%I_idx` could to produce wrong result; there is positional parameters like `%2I` to avoid something like `... tab, tab, tab ...`