# How to query postgres for jsonb field that has a key set to a null value

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have a table in postgres which has rows like the following in a `jsonb` column called `data`:

```
{ "block": { "data": null, "timestamp": "1680617159" } }
{"block": {"hash": "0xf0cab6f80ff8db4233bd721df2d2a7f7b8be82a4a1d1df3fa9bbddfe2b609e28", "size": "0x21b", "miner": "0x0d70592f27ec3d8996b4317150b3ed8c0cd57e38", "nonce": "0x1a8261f25fc22fc3", "number": "0x1847", "uncles": [], "gasUsed": "0x0", "mixHash": "0x864231753d23fb737d685a94f0d1a7ccae00a005df88c0f1801f03ca84b317eb", "gasLimit": "0x1388", "extraData": "0x476574682f76312e302e302f6c696e75782f676f312e342e32", "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", "stateRoot": "0x2754a138df13677ca025d024c6b6ac901237e2bf419dda68d9f9519a69bfe00e", "timestamp": "0x55baa522", "difficulty": "0x3f5a9c5edf", "parentHash": "0xf50f292263f296897f15fa87cb85ae8191876e90e71ab49a087e9427f9203a5f", "sealFields": [], "sha3Uncles": "0x1dcc4de8dec75d7aab85b567b6ccd41ad312451b948a7413f0a142fd40d49347", "receiptsRoot": "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421", "transactions": [], "totalDifficulty": "0x239b3c909daa6", "transactionsRoot": "0x56e81f171bcc55a6ff8345e692c0f86e5b48e01b996cadc001622fb5e363b421"}, "transaction_receipts": []}
```

I'd like to write a SQL query which selects all rows that have a `null` value for `block.data` but does not select rows which do not have a `data` field.

I've tried the following, and they all have failed:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data->>'block'->>'data' IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE data->'block'->'data' IS NULL;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE jsonb_extract_path_text(data, 'block', 'data') IS NULL;
```

It seems that in all of these cases, if the `data` field isn't present, it passes the `where` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `'null'::jsonb` in the condition:

```sql
select *
from my_table
where data->'block'->'data' = 'null'
```

Other answers, however effective, are unnecessarily complex and hide the essence of things. The problem is that the `'null'::jsonb` is not the same as Postgres `null`:

```sql
select 'null'::jsonb is null;

 ?column?
----------
 f
(1 row)
```

You can use a simple btree index that can support the first query:

```sql
create index on my_table ((data->'block'->'data'));
```

Alternatively, the gin index can support the `@>` operator:

```sql
create index on my_table using gin ((data->'block'->'data'));

select *
from my_table
where data->'block'->'data' @> 'null';
```

Comment: I think you may have a typo in your answer (`'null'::jsonb` vs `'null'`) but yes, this is by far the cleanest. Do you have any suggestions for what sort of index I could use to make this query faster?

Comment: wonderful thank you! I'll give that btree index a shot and see how it helps. I'd guess the btree index will be much smaller than the GIN index, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, gin index seems to be a bit redundant in the case.

Comment: The btree index worked perfectly. The query is now super fast even on ~17 million rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the '@>' operator to check if `'{"data":null}'` is contained in the data->'block' path.

```
SELECT *
FROM tab
WHERE (data->'block') @> '{"data":null}'
```

**Output**:

| data |
| --- |
| {"block":{"data":null,"timestamp":"1680617159"}} |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/x1NiTjoEBcPqhVDmCzdpC1/2).

Comment: wonderful thank you! This query works but it's super slow. Is there a way to create an index on just specific keys (or specific paths) in the json column so speed this up?

Comment: `(data->>'block')::JSONB` can be simplified to `data->'block'`

Comment: Would you expect a performance benefit from that @a_horse_with_no_name? Or is it just for conciseness?

Comment: Unfortunately, I think there's not much optimization to be carried out on json operations... for further infos, you could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71088092/12492890), or probably @a_horse_with_no_name is likely to give more insights in this regard definitely.

Comment: Well, it should be faster because you are not converting a jsonb value to text to convert it back to jsonb. But I don't know if you could measure the difference. But I find it much cleaner.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name do you have any suggestions for indexes (or any other mechanism) to speed up this query? I just did some research on GIN indexes and it's not clear to me if a GIN index would help in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Use two predicates to see if the key exists *and if the value is `null`

```
where jsonb_path_exists(data,'$.block.data') and 
jsonb_path_query_first(data,'$.block') ->> 'data' is null;
```

**Example**

```
with test as ( 
select 1 id, '{ "block": { "data": null, "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb  as data union all
select 2 id, '{ "block": { "data": 1, "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb as data union all
select 3 id, '{ "block": {  "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb as data)
select t.id
from test t 
where jsonb_path_exists(data,'$.block.data') and 
jsonb_path_query_first(data,'$.block') ->> 'data' is null;

id|
--+
 1|
```

This query leads to an `Seq Scan`of the table as shown below

```
explain analyze
select t.id
from test t 
where jsonb_path_exists(data,'$.block.data') and 
jsonb_path_query_first(data,'$.block') ->> 'data' is null;

Seq Scan on test t  (cost=10000000000.00..10000003289.05 rows=167 width=4) (actual time=45.745..68.798 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (jsonb_path_exists(data, '$."block"."data"'::jsonpath, '{}'::jsonb, false) AND ((jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$."block"'::jsonpath, '{}'::jsonb, false) ->> 'data'::text) IS NULL))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 100002
Planning Time: 0.079 ms
JIT:
  Functions: 4
  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true
  Timing: Generation 0.714 ms, Inlining 8.161 ms, Optimization 26.128 ms, Emission 11.304 ms, Total 46.308 ms
 Execution Time: 69.586 ms  <<<--------------
```

If you have a very low number of rows with the `data` key defined, you may profit from  the index

```
CREATE INDEX idx_test2 ON test USING btree (((jsonb_path_exists(data,'$.block.data'))));
```

The plan uses the index and is much more performant

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on test t  (cost=551.35..2965.38 rows=167 width=4) (actual time=0.034..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
  Filter: (jsonb_path_exists(data, '$."block"."data"'::jsonpath, '{}'::jsonb, false) AND ((jsonb_path_query_first(data, '$."block"'::jsonpath, '{}'::jsonb, false) ->> 'data'::text) IS NULL))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 1
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_test2  (cost=0.00..551.31 rows=50002 width=0) (actual time=0.025..0.025 rows=2 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (jsonb_path_exists(data, '$."block"."data"'::jsonpath, '{}'::jsonb, false) = true)
Planning Time: 0.164 ms
Execution Time: 0.052 ms  <<<--------------
```

*Used test data*

```
create table test as
select 1 id, '{ "block": { "data": null, "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb  as data, repeat('x',2000) pad union all
select 2 id, '{ "block": { "data": 1, "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb as data, repeat('x',2000) pad union all
select 3 id, '{ "block": {  "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb as data, repeat('x',2000) pad union all
select id+3, '{ "block": {  "timestamp": "1680617159" } }'::jsonb as data, repeat('x',2000) pad from generate_series(1,100000) as t(id )
;
```

Comment: Would you expect this solution to be faster than the other proposed solution? Alternatively, would this solution benefit from indexes?