# Query with calculated column based of json type values

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is it possible to create a calulated column using the values of json in postgresl ie -

I want to add longitude and latitude together as a new calculated column named total

```
SELECT id, location -> 'long' as long, location -> 'lat' as lat, (long + lat) as total
FROM users
```

All help appreciated Thanks

Comment: Where is the json ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Computed / calculated / virtual / derived columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389/computed-calculated-virtual-derived-columns-in-postgresql)