# PostgreSQL Computed Column with Format ('TR-'+format([Id],'0000000000'))

Tags: postgresql, generated-columns

I am new to Postgres and I need to create computed column to format request number as below

```
TR-000000001
TR-000000011
TR-000000111
```

in SQL server i handled it as follow

```
('TR-'+format([Id],'0000000000'))
```

and it works fine

How can I do this using PostgreSQL

Comment: With which part exactly of [the documented syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) do you have a problem?

Comment: return syntax error with keyword (format)  - ('TR-'+format([Id],'0000000000'))

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.5.2.2.1.1.1.1) the concatenation operator in standard SQL (and PostgreSQL) is `||` - the `+` is for adding numbers.

The syntax to define a generated columns is also [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) and follows the pattern:

```
 <column name> <data type> generated always as (<expression>) stored
```

To convert a number to a string with leading `0`, you can use the [lpad()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#id-1.5.8.10.7.2.2.11.1.1.1) function.

Putting this all together, you are looking for something like:

```
create table the_table 
(
  id int primary key,
  formatted_id text generated always as ('TR-'||lpad(id::text, 10, '0')) stored
);
```